# ¿Se pueden quitar los bordes de una interface en PyQT5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

En una aplicación hecha con PyQT5 se crea normalmente un borde alrededor de la misma, es posible quitarlo? si es así cómo se pueden quitar?